# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'meetingId' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a dropdownlist and I am trying to insert the `DataValueField` into a database table. The `DataValueField` is retrieved from the database and the data type for the column is `INT`. However, when the run the query I get this error message

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'meetingId' to data type int.

Code:

```
if (MinuteUpload.HasFile)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    string updateSql = "UPDATE Project_Meeting SET meetingMinute = @meetingMinute WHERE meetingId = @MeetingId"; ;

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSql, myConnection);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meetingMinute", "postUpload/" + filename);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingId", MinuteDropDown.DataValueField);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

However, when I try

```
Convert.ToIint.TryParse16(MinuteDropDown.DataValueField.Trim())
```

I get this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: I like this blog poist by one of the SO users -> http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: `MinuteDropDown.DataValueField` is the _name_ of the dropdown field. You need to use the dropdown's value. I think you would have found this if you had walked the code in a debugger. @GordonLinoff Your guess is incorrect. The error says it all. The string value `"meetingId"` cannot be converted to an `int`.

Comment: @JLRishe . . . You should add that as an answer.  It seems like the likely cause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was going to, but Joe Enos beat me to it. I'll upvote him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingId", MinuteDropDown.DataValueField);
```

There are two things wrong. First, `DataValueField` represents the name of the property, not the value of the property. `SelectedValue` is what you want.

But once you make that change, `SelectedValue` is still a string. You should parse that into an `int` in advance, before adding your parameter:

```
int meetingId = int.Parse(MinuteDropDown.SelectedValue);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingId", meetingId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the parameter. Assuming your meetingId field is of type int:

```
// replace this line
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeetingId", MinuteDropDown.DataValueField);
// with
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@MeetingId", SqlDbType.Int);
myCommand.Parameters("@MeetingId").Value = MinuteDropDown.DataValueField;
```